# UDP Pinger Assignment

Tags: python, networking, server, udp

I have been trying to code a UDP client/server in python (as seen at bottom). 
The code works and runs. But, I believe there is something wrong with the line:

```
    try:
        data, server = client_socket.recvfrom(1024) **# THIS LINE** 
        end = time.time()
        elapsed = end - start
        print(f'{data} {pings} {elapsed}')
```

When I run the code, it prints out the counter, the current time, and "REQUEST TIMED OUT" ten times as I would like it to. I have no idea why! I did so much research and tried other people's code but none of which are working! Please help!

Server:

```
import random
from socket import *

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', 12000))

while True:
    rand = random.randint(0, 10)    
    message, address = serverSocket.recvfrom(1024)
    message = message.upper()

    if rand < 4:
        continue
    serverSocket.sendto(message, address)
```

Client:

```
import time
import socket

count = 0

for pings in range(10):
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    client_socket.settimeout(1.0)
    message = b'test'
    address = ("127.0.0.1", 12000)

    start = time.time()
    client_socket.sendto(message, address)

    count = count +1
    print(count, "\n", "current time: ", start)


    try:
        data, server = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        end = time.time()
        elapsed = end - start
        print(f'{data} {pings} {elapsed}')

    except socket.timeout:
        print('REQUEST TIMED OUT')
```

Comment: Do you realize that port 1024 is a reserved port? Ports ar the start and end of a grouping are reserved, and they are not allowed to be used. You can check ports on the _[IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)_, along with the various RFCs

Comment: Port 1024 is not being utilized. The recvfrom() argument is specifying the buffer size. The port (12000 in this case) is specified in the bind() and sendto() calls, in the server and client, respectively.

Comment: @k.le Is the server running before you execute the client? Are you using python3? Are you trying to simulate packet loss (i.e. the "if rand < 4" statement)?